# Customized port is not functional in Docker-compose

Tags: docker, server, ip, docker-compose

I'm having a dumb question regarding to using `docker-compose`.

Current scenario is I'm trying use my `reverse_proxy` to talk to my `frontend_server`. Inside the `reverse_proxy`, It redirects to `frontend_server` just like the following:

Suppose I receive `http://${REV_IP}:${REV_PORT}` It should redirect me to `http://${FE_IP}:${FE_PORT}` but it redirect me to `15000`

(PROXIED_FRONTEND is `http://${FE_IP}:${FE_PORT}`, this environment veriable is used for this redirection)

Here is the code snippet for my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'
services:
  reverse_proxy:
    image: "${ARTIFACTORY}/template-reverse-proxy:${BRANCH}-${REV_TAG}"
    networks:
      nucleus-network:
        ipv4_address: ${REV_IP}
    ports:
      - "${REV_PORT}:15999"
    environment:
      - KEYFILE_REVPROXY=${REV_KEY}
      - CERTFILE_REVPROXY=${REV_CERT}
      - PUBLIC_URL=${PUBLIC_URL}
      - PUBLIC_API_URL=${PUBLIC_API_URL}
      - PROXIED_FRONTEND=${PROXIED_FRONTEND}
      - PROXIED_PDF=${PROXIED_PDF}
    depends_on:
      - frontend_server
  frontend_server:
      image: "${ARTIFACTORY}/fe_server:${BRANCH}-${PDF_TAG}"
      ports:
        - "${FE_PORT}:15000"
      networks:
        nucleus-network:
          ipv4_address: ${FE_IP}
      environment:
        - FILEPATH_FE_SERVER=${FILEPATH_FE_SERVER}
      volumes:
        - "/home/lluo/dist_share:/app/dist"
      depends_on:
        - frontend_static 
networks:
  nucleus-network:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
       - subnet: ${SUB_NET}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's no need for you to publish frontend_server port to outside world (via ports:), unless you want to access it directly (i.e. for debugging)

Since you use docker-compose and depends_on, it will create you a inner docker network, in which containers will see each other.

Only thing for you to do is to setup your reverse proxy to have the proxied backend pointing to `http://frontend_server:15000` and your good to go. inner docker DNS will resolve the `frontend_sever` service name to appropriate container IP address.

for reference and more info see this question and links provided there: https://serverfault.com/questions/800689/how-to-use-haproxy-in-load-balancing-and-as-a-reverse-proxy-with-docker